# Obstacle avoidance with pure Vision approach?

Tags: camera, object-detection

I would like to do obstacle avoidance using pure Vision approach. I will use ROS and Ubuntu as a framework. The application is in construction industry so would like to detect the material winch is handling by the crane to perform obstacle avoidance . My question is , if its possible to use only vision approach for obstacle avoidance where the distance form the camera to the object can be 30-40m. I will use the zoom for better approach. If its possible to use only Vision camera any starting algorithm to look at it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would start looking into **Visual Odometry** and **SLAM**. I advice you to read about these techniques more thoroughly, but here's a quick explanation:

**Visual Odometry** algorithms use features on a video feed in order to locate the camera in an environment. By looking in the movement of these features, the movement of the camera can be approximated.

**SLAM** (Simultaneous Location and Mapping) is a technique used to both locate a robot/device and map the unknown environment. This is very useful when you don't know the environment you are going to deploy your robot or if the environment changes. Using probabilities, the SLAM methods can infer with some certainty, where the robot and the obstacles are.

When **combining these two**, you have a method that can locate and avoid obstacles using only the feed of a digital camera. This is still a quite complex achievement, but there are already some methods that will allow you to start.

There are also several types of cameras used in robotics. The most common for this purpose are **Monocular** (normal camera), **Stereo** (two cameras around 10 cm apart) and **RGB-D** (also called depth cameras with a normal and an IR camera ex: the kinect for Xbox)

Since you didn't specify the camera you are using I will assume a Monocular set-up, but you can easily find methods for your type of camera, just google "RGB-D Visual SLAM" for example.

Known methods for a Monocular set-up (some also support Stereo and RGB-D):

- [LSD-SLAM: Large-Scale Direct Monocular SLAM](https://vision.in.tum.de/research/vslam/lsdslam)
- [DSO: Direct Sparse Odometry](https://vision.in.tum.de/research/vslam/dso)
- [SVO 2.0: Fast Semi-Direct Visual Odometry for Monocular, Wide Angle, and Multi-camera Systems](http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/svo2.html)
- [PTAM: Parallel Tracking and Mapping for Small AR Workspaces](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~gk/PTAM/) - sometimes considered the father of visual odometry

And my personal favorite:

- [ORB-SLAM2](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2)

These techniques try to build a map with the features they use to locate themselves. Depending on the approach, these features may be considered obstacles and may be used for obstacle avoidance or even complex trajectory planning.

Search on youtube to see some of these techniques in action and see which one suits you better ;)

Here are some for the ORB-SLAM2:
[Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cx94iW5SrGY&t=39s)
[Video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIR7NgsMt6U)

Comment: Thanks. I will build my own collision detection/obstacle avoidance system but would like to use Visual SLAM. So do I still need the Visual odometry and if yes for what do I need it? I will use machine learning techniques to classified the objects. any help?

Comment: Visual SLAM uses Visual Odometry, it's not exclusive. Basically, Visual SLAM uses the Visual Odometry characteristics to do both location and mapping. It is basically a combination of Visual Odometry and SLAM.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this open source project [GAAS](https://github.com/generalized-intelligence/GAAS) built for vision-based autonomous drones
It uses stereo cameras and SLAM.

It has a detailed [step-by-step instruction](https://github.com/generalized-intelligence/GAAS/tree/master/demo) to get you started on the infrastructure of vision-based obstacle detection.

Comment: Links are great, but it would be even more helpful if you could summarize a possible way to correct the problem outlined in the question.

Comment: The project GAAS is an infrastructure that will help him achieve the obstacle avoidance goal. In order for anyone to provide more details, we would need to know the size of the obstacles and the size of the drone. (Larger drone can have a larger stereo camera, and thus greater detection range)